# Parsing this nested JSON code php

Tags: php, json

I've looked through a lot of answers and tried to get this to work but it's not printing. Could someone please help?

my json string:

```
$string=
    '{“logpile”:[{
        “machinemodel”  :”Model#”,
        “machineserial” :”Serial”,
        “logs”:{
            "data":[
                {
                    “day”   :”YYYY-MM-DD:hh:mm:ss”,
                    “code”  :”OPTIME”,   
                    “value” :”2345234”
                },
                {
                    “day”   :”YYYY-MM-DD:hh:mm:ss”,
                    “code”  :”ES01”,
                    “value” :”Fries”
                }
               ]
        }
}]}';
```

my attempt to decode:

```
$decoded = json_decode($string);
$comments = $decoded->logpile[0]->logs->data;
foreach($comments as $comment){
   $name = $comment->day;
   $message = $comment->value;
   echo $name;
   echo $value;
}
```

Comment: Are those curly quotes actually in your code?

Comment: Stop using WORD as a source editor, its not one

Comment: If you simply fix the smartquotes (change them to normal double quotes) your code pretty much just works (after you change `$value` to `$message`): https://3v4l.org/3aKsl

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the curly quotes, maybe they are the problem. I copy-pasted the JSON from a google doc I was working with someone on this with. im not using WORD.

Comment: Google doc does smart quotes like Word does. I assume that in the real application you get the JSON from an API, it should not have this problem.

Comment: Thanks guys. It works now.

Comment: Can I choose a best answer as a comment?